# Как вывести определенное значение из БД в EF?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

```
using (ApplicationContext db = new ApplicationContext())
{
    Team team = db.Teams
        .Include(p => p.Players)
        .Include(a => a.Stadium)
        .FirstOrDefault();

    Console.WriteLine($"Team :{team.Name}");
    foreach (var item in team.Players)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Player {item.Name} Country {item.Country}");
    }
```

Хотелось вывести не первую команду, а допустим третью, но код

```
Team team = db.Teams.Where(a => a.Id == 3).ToList();
```

выводит ошибку!

> Error CS0029  Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<ConsoleApp50.Team>' to 'ConsoleApp50.Team'  ConsoleApp50    C:\Users\PC\source\repos\ConsoleApp50\ConsoleApp50\Program.cs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте данным методом.

```
int n = 2;
var nthItem = items.Skip(n).First();
```

В вашем коде ошибка. ToList вернет List.
Т.е. либо так:

```
 Team team = db.Teams.Where(a => a.Id == 3).FirstOrDefault();
```

Либо так:

```
 List<Team> team = db.Teams.Where(a => a.Id == 3).ToList();
```

Comment: Спасибо, у меня вопрос, какая есть хороший портал, для изучения EF  или книга для закрепления и углубления фреймворка.

Comment: Официальная документация, на мой субъективный взгляд, лучший проводник. Плюс личный опыт и перенимаемые навыки.